# Create SSL certificate for backend

Tags: node.js, express, ssl-certificate

I have the problem that the domain name in my vue frontend certificate doesn't match the backend, cause it's just running on an IP. So I tried to create a SSL cert for it and get the error "Cannot issue for IP address: The ACME server can not issue a certificate for an IP address".
So how exactly do I create a SSL cert for my express backend then?

Comment: There is absolute nothing bad against creating a certificate for an IP address. How are you creating it?

Comment: I'm using "certbot certonly --manual"  and typing the address. @Alejandro

Comment: Maybe I need a public domain cause the servers can't reach my IP...
But how would I solve this issue then?

Comment: `certbot` just forwards your request to let's encrypt, and they don't issue certificates for IP addresses. Either use another certificate provider that supports them, or use your domain name for it.

Comment: @Alejandro I'm using my domain name at the frontend. But the backend can't be reached through it. And that's why I get errors on chrome, when trying to login for example.

Comment: You'll need a domain name if you want to use Let's Encrypt. Not that's not possible to do so, but they simply won't do it. You'll need to assing a domain name to that server (the same you're already using, a subdomain, or another one, as you want) or switch to another certificate provider. Look at their official response here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ssl-on-a-ip-instead-of-domain/90635

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you very much for you help! I created a self-signed certs and that did the trick. :)